# How do you move between nodes of a linked list?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

This is a piece of code that tries to build a linked list.

```
struct node {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int height;
    node* next; // Pointer to the next node
};
node* startPTR = NULL;

void addNode_AT_END() {
    node *temp1;
    node *temp2;

    temp1 = new node;  

    cout << "Enter the name : ";
    cin  >> temp1->name;
    cout << endl << "Enter the age : ";
    cin  >> temp1->age;
    cout << endl << "Enter height : ";
    cin  >> temp1->height;

    temp1->next = NULL;

    if( startPTR == NULL) {
       startPTR = temp1; 
    }  else {
       temp2 = startPTR;

       while( temp2->next != NULL )
           temp2 = temp2->next;

       temp2->next = temp1;
    }
 }
```

The following is diagram after 2 back to back calls to the above function.

```
start = addr1;
|
V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)      at end
^
|
temp2
```

where addr1 and addr2 are the address of the first and second nodes respectively.

**What happens after the third call ? How the iteration will go on for the third call?** I am unable to understand how the `list` links up after the second call.According to me all that has been build up till know will vanish.Then how will list move further ? How is node placed during the third call?

Comment: What?  The code posted is a pretty typical linked list implementation.  What is specific about the 3rd call that is confusing?

Comment: @ Chad how will the iteration carry on in the third call ?

Comment: See the correct answers below.

Comment: I found the best way to figure out pointers is to take out pencil and paper (remember those? They were quite popular last century). Then go through the code line by line and draw what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is where all the magic happens:

```
1. temp2 = startPTR;
2. while( temp2->next != NULL )
3.    temp2 = temp2->next;
4. temp2->next = temp1;
```

First, `temp2` will point to the beginning of the list. In lines 2 and 3, you change `temp2` to the next node until you reach the node where `temp2->next` is `NULL`. This node is the last node of the list, regardless of the size of the list.

Finally, in line 4 you change `temp2->next` to `temp1` so now it points to the new node (that is last node now points to the new node). `temp1->next` is also `NULL`, so `temp1` now represents the end of the list.

After line 1 you have

```
start = addr1;
|
V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)
^
|
temp2
```

`temp2->next` is not `NULL` (it is addr2), so you iterate and execute line 3 and you get:

```
start = addr1;
|
V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)
              ^
              |
              temp2
```

`temp2->next` is now `NULL`. So you stop the loop and execute line 4 and you get:

```
start = addr1;
|
V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (addr3) ----> (NULL)
              ^             ^
              |             |
              temp2         temp1
```

**Note**: Do you know how pointers work? Imagine this: You have a node, which is some data in the memory. When you have variables in memory, these variables have addresses. Let's say addr1 is 10, addr2 is 150 and addr3 (which is the node just `new`ed) is 60. `start` has value 10. Therefore, "pointing" to the first node of the list (that is using this address, you have access to its data). One of these data, is the `next` field. The first node's `next` field has value 150, thus pointing to the next node. When you say `temp2 = start`, you put number 10 in `temp2`, at this point `temp2->next` has value 150. When you say `temp2=temp2->next`, you simply put value 150 in `temp2`, overwriting the previous value. This way you have effectively moved your pointer from pointing to the first node, to now pointing to the second node. Now `temp2->next` is `NULL` (that is 0). When you now say `temp2->next=temp1`, you put value 60 in the `next` field of `temp2`. So now `temp2->next` is 60. `temp2->next->next` is `NULL`.

Comment: ok. But i am asking how in iteration you traverse the list.Because during the third call you don't the address of the second node. So when you write `startPTR->next` how does it point to the second node.

Comment: I just finished editing my answer. If you still have a question after reading the note, tell me.

Comment: The thing is, the memory is there. **The address of the second node is stored in the `next` field of the first node**, so through the first node you have access to the second node. Likewise, from the second node to the third, from the third to the fourth and hence the while loop.

Comment: `temp2->next = temp1` which assigns the address of the second node to the first node is actually stored in the memory ?

Comment: Of course. The `next` field is just a variable like any other. When you say `temp2->next = ...` then that variable (`next`) which is in the memory is set.

Comment: can i use `temp2++` instead of `temp2->next` in the condition of while loop ?

Comment: when the function is called the third time and the while loop works how does `temp2->next` return the address of the next node ? Previously i had jumped to other linked pointers using **pointer++** . Please explain this

Comment: No, when you `++` a pointer, you go ahead in the memory, which is useful when moving in array of nodes because the nodes there are placed contiguously. With linked lists however, you `new` each node, and thus the nodes of the linked list are scattered around the memory. For example, if size of node is 10, and you have `node1` has address 50, `node2` has address 200 and `node3` has address 150, then you say `node1->next = 200` and therefore, in the variable `next` of `node1`, you store the address of `node2`, therefore linking them. `node1++` would have given you 60, which is not even valid!

Comment: `temp2->next` has the address of next node stored in it (when `temp2->next = temp1;` is executed, that happens). By saying `temp2 = temp2->next;` you simply take that address (which is a simple number) and put it in `temp2` again, therefore reusing the variable `temp2`. If that confuses you, imagine writing `temp3 = temp2->next; temp2 = temp3;`

Comment: If you still don't understand this, I suggest you start learning pointers from scratch, learn the difference between what is a variable and what is an address. Learn what operators `&` and `*` do. Your questions seem like you have misunderstood the basics of pointers. Believe me, if you understand the simplicity of pointers, all of these becomes trivial to you.

Comment: @program-o-steve, is your issue resolved? Did you learn how that code works or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. The while cycle will move temp2 to the last element. Then the node you created, pointed by temp1, is assigned as temp2's next node

Comment: **And can you please tell how the cycle will move temp2 to the last element** ? Where was the list that we had build till step 2 ? How does temp2->next point to the next element ?

Comment: The only element whose next pointer is NULL is the last element. You only have to do p=p->next till you reach a NULL next pointer

Comment: how do i reach there using p=p->next ? How does it know the previous address? This is my bloody question

Comment: It doesn't need to. It's pointless to know the previous address because you are only moving forward. Basically, p->next is the pointer to the next element. Doing p=p->next you are just making p point to the following element. Once p->next is NULL, p point surely to the last element

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what's bothering you. During any call while() loop will go through all the nodes in the list untill it reaches the end, and then set the pointer in the last one to the newly allocated node (temp1).

temp1 and temp2 are pointers. they do not store data of the node, they store address in memory where data is stored. so at the end of first iteration, after `startPTR = temp1` startPTR points to the same address that temp1 pointed to. it doesn't matter if temp1 is still there, since now startPTR points to the node. at the end of the second call `temp2->next=temp1` (temp2==startPTR at this moment) makes `next` field of the node  point to the newly allocated `temp1`

Comment: temp2 is a pointer. during the while() loop you "move" it, so it points to the last node. so when you set `temp2->next=temp1` you are actually setting `"lastnode"->next=temp1`